# Не работает javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

В HTML-коде есть элемент с неким id:

```
<div class="hoom" id="boom"></div>
```

В подключённом js-файле есть функция:

```
$('.hoom').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
var text=$('#textarea').val();
jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"ajax/rel.php",data:{'id':id,'text':text},success:function(html){$("#con").append(html);}});
});
```

В файле rel.php переменные id и text записываются в БД и публикуются в блок id='con'. У каждой записи есть кнопки + и -, с помощью которых пользователь может оценить запись; для того, чтобы они работали, в файле rel.php подключен ещё один js-файл.

Проблема в том, что кнопки + и - начинают работать после того, как публикуется ещё одна запись. То есть:

Передаём и публикуем: id=4; text='Hello'. Кнопки не работают.<br>
Передаём и публикуем: id=4; text='Goodbye'. Кнопки работают только у запись с 'Hello'.<br>
Передаём и публикуем: id=4; text='Fuck'. Кнопки работают только у первых двух записей.<br>

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle

Comment: Попробуйте заменить  

    $('.hoom').click(function(){  

На  

    $('body').on('click', '.hoom', function(){

Comment: Уже исправил. Пришлось делать через onclick...